# Equivalent python code for curl command for https call

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

I have a curl command that works and gives me back the JSON.
Curl command:

```
    curl -sS -k -L -H "Authorization: bearer <token>" -X GET https://IP:PORT/api/v1/namespaces
```

I tried with `requests`and `pycurl` modules which I found in the other posts but no luck.

Can anyone help me with finding the equivalent in python???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with requests like this:

```
import requests
header = {'Authorization': 'bearer <token>'}
resp = requests.get("https://IP:PORT/api/v1/namespaces", 
    headers = header, 
    verify=False)
print(resp.status_code)
print(resp.text)
```

- The `-H` switch behaviour is replicated by sending a header
- The `-L` switch behaviour is replicated by specifying `verify=False`
- The `-sS` and `-k` are about the behaviour of curl and not relevant here
- The `-X GET` is replicated by using `requests.get()`

Comment: Thanks, it works, the token I had was also not correct. Thanks again.